# How to call a program unit from an oracle forms using java

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms

I need to call a PL / SQL function that is in an Oracle Forms and not in the database. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Searching the internet I found how to call a Java method in a PL / SQL function, but not the other way around. I need to capture this function, which is inside an Oracle Forms (Program Unit) and pass the necessary parameters in order to simulate a behavior for my automated test. I thank the help of all you.

I will try to exemplify. In my OracleForms I have the following function:

```
FUNCTION FN_MYFUNCTION_WS(P_CD_PERSON NUMBER,P_CD_TYPE VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'V') RETURN NUMBER IS
vRetorno number := 1;
BEGIN
   /*code here*/
End;
```

If the function was saved in the database, I could access it using a CallableStatement object like this:

```
    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
    if (conn != null) {

        CallableStatement cstm = conn.prepareCall("begin ? := fn_myfunction_ws(?, ?); end;");
        cstm.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        cstm.setInt(2, cdPerson);
        cstm.setString(3, "V");
        cstm.executeUpdate();
        String outFunc = cstm.getString(1);
    }
```

The problem is that the function is not in the database but inside oracle forms and I don't know if there is a way to access it.

Comment: move the pl/sql function in the form into a package into the db, and then call it from the form and java.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option.

Comment: OK then you are probably out of luck then

Comment: You can share a concrete example about what you have as PL/SQL function and Java method by editing your question.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I edited the post with sample code.